# How to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core with version 3.1.0 from NuGet?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a `netstandard2.0` class library project, which depend on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` with  version **2.1.1**.
I am presently trying to upgrade this project to `netstardand2.1`,being used by a `netcore3.1` application, but I find that the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core with version **3.1.0** is not available on NuGet? Where can I find this package?

Comment: You really should create a .NET Core class library, and then follow this guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found this solution in ASP.NET Core 3.1 documentation.

> *With the release of .NET Core 3.0, many ASP.NET Core assemblies are no longer published to NuGet as packages. Instead, the assemblies are
> included in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App shared framework, which is
> installed with the .NET Core SDK and runtime installers. For a list of
> packages no longer being published,  see [Remove obsolete package
> references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references)*
>
> *As of .NET Core 3.0, projects using the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web MSBuild SDK implicitly reference the shared framework. Projects using the
> Microsoft.NET.Sdk or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor SDK must reference
> ASP.NET Core to use ASP.NET Core APIs in the shared framework.*
>
> *To reference ASP.NET Core, add the following  element to your project file:* (`*.csproj file`)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

For more details visit this link: [Use ASP.NET Core APIs in a class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#determine-which-aspnet-core-versions-to-support)

Answer (score 5):

We have to add below tags on *.csproj file?

```
<ItemGroup>
   <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I added, my net core class worked now!